# Scrapy FormRequest can't handle complex dicts as formdata

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, form-data, scrapy-shell

I am trying to provide formdata to a scrapy.FormRequest object. The formdata is a dict of the following structure:

```
{
  "param1": [
    {
      "paramA": "valueA",
      "paramB": "valueB"
    }
  ]
}
```

via equivalent to the following code, run in scrapy shell:

```
from scrapy import FormRequest

url = 'www.example.com'
method_post = 'POST'
formdata = <the above dict>

fr = FormRequest(url=url, method=method_post, formdata=formdata)

fetch(fr)
```

and in response I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/chhk/.local/share/virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 31, in __init__
    querystr = _urlencode(items, self.encoding)
  File "/Users/chhk/.local/share/virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 66, in _urlencode
    for k, vs in seq
  File "/Users/chhk/.local/share/virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 67, in <listcomp>
    for v in (vs if is_listlike(vs) else [vs])]
  File "/Users/chhk/.local/share/virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 119, in to_bytes
    'object, got %s' % type(text).__name__)
TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got dict
```

I have tried a variety of solutions, including the whole thing as a string, with various escape characters, and variations on the dict to make it more agreeable, but none of the solutions that remove this error work for the request (I get a 400 response).

I know that the formdata and that everything else I am doing is correct, in that I have replicated it successfully in curl (formdata was provided via `-d formdata.txt`).

Is there a way around FormRequest's inability to deal with complex dict structures? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `formdata` you can try to use `body` parameter. Example:

```
FormRequest(url=url, method=method_post, body=json.dumps(formdata))
```

Comment: You're a genius and have made my day much better. Also, how can I find out more about putting formdata in the body? I've never heard of that.

Comment: `FormRequest` inherits from `Request` (https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/http/request/form.py#L20), so it can use the same fields as parent: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

You can even change to simple Request with POST method.

```
import headers
headers = {
    # some headers
}
payload = json.dumps(formdata)
Request(
    url,
    headers=headers,
    method='POST',
    body=payload,
)
```